# get ora 12514 when connecting 12c to sql developer

Tags: oracle, database-connection, tnsnames, ora-12514

My procedure:
1. [checking container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix5W5.png) ,
2. [altering container n unlocking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FoW0.jpg)

I made the following addition to tnsnames.ora

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

I have unlocked the hr account and I mention `pdborcl` as service name while making the connection.

my listener.ora

```
  # listener.ora Network Configuration File:       C:\Users\SURBHI\Documents\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
  # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

 SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
    (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\SURBHI\Documents\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
    (PROGRAM = extproc)
    (ENVS =      "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Users\SURBHI\Documents\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr1     2.dll")
      )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
         (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

I have tried several things like using tnsping pdborcl on command prompt which gives OK result.

But I am not getting positive result till now.

Comment: what about service names from `%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora` ? Are there is a pdborcl serivce? Are you restart listener after create it?

Comment: @Michael Piankov ,hope my edits  are clearer now n describe what you are asking.

Comment: what's your connection properties look like when setting up your connection? try a direct connection type with the SERVICE name

Comment: @thatjeffsmith,I give a connection name, username=hr,password=hr.Under connection type ,I choose basic and role as default.The hostname is localhost and port is 1521.Then I select the service name radio buttton  and write PDBORCL as the service name.The error persists.

Comment: if you run this from a cmd prompt, do you see PDBORCL listed? > lsnrctl status

Comment: When I run lsnrctl status,nowhere is pdborcl listed.Under the service summary there is CLRExtProc,PLSExtproc,XEXDB,xe.I learnt from certain YOUTUBE tutorial that we need to need to connect to pluggable database for hr connection and choosing SID and xe would give an error,which exactly happens with me as well.So trying the pdborcl...